# Combining affine transformations and COMPOUNDCRS

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, well-known-text, affine-transformation

I have a need to define a WKT CRS which is both affine-transformed in 2D, and vertically shifted in the height direction. What I would like to say is something like this:

```
COMPOUNDCRS["Modified MGA2020 zone 56",
  DERIVEDPROJCRS["MGA2020 zone 56 rotated",
    BASEPROJCRS["GDA2020 / MGA zone 56",
        BASEGEOGCRS["GDA2020",
            DATUM["Geocentric_Datum_of_Australia_2020",
                SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101],
                ID["EPSG",1168]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]
            ],
            ID["EPSG",7844]
        ],
        CONVERSION["Map Grid of Australia zone 56",
            METHOD["Transverse Mercator", ID["EPSG",9807]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8801]
            ],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",153,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8802]
            ],
            PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
                SCALEUNIT["unity",1], ID["EPSG",8805]
            ],
            PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1], ID["EPSG",8806]
            ],
            PARAMETER["False northing",10000000,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1], ID["EPSG",8807]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    DERIVINGCONVERSION["Affine",
        METHOD["Affine parametric transformation", ID["EPSG",9624]],
        PARAMETER["A0",1216497.2671545935,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1], ID["EPSG",8623]
        ],
        PARAMETER["A1",0.984807753012208,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1], ID["EPSG",8624]
        ],
        PARAMETER["A2",-0.17364817766693033,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1], ID["EPSG",8625]
        ],
        PARAMETER["B0",18499.726080242544,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1], ID["EPSG",8639]
        ],
        PARAMETER["B1",0.17364817766693033,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1], ID["EPSG",8640]
        ],
        PARAMETER["B2",0.984807753012208,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1], ID["EPSG",8641]
        ]
    ],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
    AXIS["(E)", east, ORDER[1], LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    AXIS["(N)", north, ORDER[2], LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]
  ],
  VERTCRS["AHD plus 2m",
    BASEVERTCRS["AHD height",
        VDATUM["Australian Height Datum"],
        ID["EPSG",5711]
    ],
    DERIVINGCONVERSION["vertical offset",
        METHOD["Vertical Offset", ID["EPSG",8603]],
        PARAMETER["Vertical Offset",2.0,
          LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]
    ],
    CS[vertical,1],
    AXIS["gravity-related height (H)", up, LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]
  ]
]
```

However, this isn't valid. According to [the spec](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/as/18-005r4/18-005r4.html):

- Section 9.3 says that only geographic 2D, projected 2D, and engineering 1D/2D are valid options for the horizontal component.
- The footnote in section 9.2.2 reminds us that, despite what the name would suggest, a derived projected CRS is not a projected CRS.

Affine-transforming the COMPOUNDCRS would of course be nice, if possible. And the area is small enough that an engineering CRS for the horizontal component *might* work, if it can be rotated and the correct vertical datum shift can be applied. I'd need to test that for accuracy.

These affine/offset transformations are of course trivial to do in a program and relatively easy to do in a PROJ pipeline, but I'm under some tool constraints which would make things much easier if this were expressible in WKT.

Any ideas?